# Separate chars of a file in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, chars

I have strings of 32 chars in a file (multiple lines).
What I want to do is to make a new file and put them there by making columns of 4 chars each.

For example I have:

```
00000000000FDAD000DFD00ASD00

00000000000FDAD000DFD00ASD00

00000000000FDAD000DFD00ASD00

....
```

and in the new file, I want them to appear like this:

```
0000 0000 000F DAD0 00DF D00A SD00

0000 0000 000F DAD0 00DF D00A SD00
```

Can you anybody help me? I am working for hours now and I can't find the solution.

Comment: Since you have been working on this for some time, please show us what code you have so far, and explain what it doesn't do correctly.

Comment: Do you have newline separating each line?

Comment: Note that your example reports 28 chars,  not 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');
txt = textscan(fid,'%s');
fclose(fid);
```

Transform into a M by 28 char array, transpose and reshape to have a 4 char block on each column. Then add to the bottom a row of blanks and reshape back. Store each line in a cell.

```
txt = reshape(char(txt{:})',4,[]);
txt = cellstr(reshape([txt; repmat(' ',1,size(txt,2))],35,[])')
```

Write each cell/line to new file

```
fid = fopen('test2.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',txt{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, open the input file and read the lines as strings:

```
infid = fopen(infilename, 'r');
C = textscan(infid, '%s', 'delimiter', '');
fclose(infid);
```

Then use `regexprep` to split the string into space-delimited groups of 4 characters:

```
C = regexprep(C{:}, '(.{4})(?!$)', '$1 ');
```

Lastly, write the modified lines to the output file:

```
outfid = fopen(outfilename, 'w');
fprintf(outfid, '%s\n', C{:});
fclose(outfid);
```

Note that this solution is robust enough to work on lines of variable length.

Comment: I especially like the `(?!$)` do not match if at the end!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it in Matlab:

```
% read in file
fid = fopen('data10.txt');
data = textscan(fid,'%s');
fclose(fid);

% save new file
s = size(data{1});
newFid = fopen('newFile.txt','wt');
for t = 1:s(1) % format and save each row
    line = data{1}{t};
    newLine = '';
    index = 1;
    for k = 1:7 % seven sets of 4 characters
        count = 0;
        while count < 4
            newLine(end + 1) = line(index);
            index = index + 1;
            count = count + 1;
        end
        newLine(end + 1) = ' ';
    end
    fprintf(newFid, '%s\n', newLine);
end
fclose(newFid);
```